jwt.Parse Crashes Under Load in Custom Tyk Plugin
I am using the jwt.Parse function to validate tokens in a custom Tyk plugin. Under high load, the code frequently crashes, causing the gateway to fail. This issue occurs when multiple requests are sent concurrently, and the plugin tries to validate tokens. It seems related to unhandled panics or resource management problems.
func checkToken(tokenString string, key *rsa.PublicKey) bool {
    authHeader := strings.TrimPrefix(tokenString, "Bearer ")
    var token, err = jwt.Parse(
        authHeader,
        func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %s", "alg")
            }
            return key, nil
        })

    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, jwt.ErrTokenExpired) {
            logger.Error("Token is expired")
                tok = "Token is expired"
            } else {
                logger.Error("Failed to parse JWT: ", err)
                tok = "Failed to parse JWT"
            }
        return false
    }

    if !token.Valid {
        logger.Error("Token is invalid")
        tok = "Token is invalid"
        return false
    }

    return true
}

